# What are Gottfried Juch Ferlach guns?

Tags: weapons, identification

I have came into possession of a double barrel firearm, apparently for hunting. The only inscription it has is Gottfried Juch Ferlach. It is quite interesting, since it has some really beautiful engravings, like those in the picture below (they are not the same though).

[image]

What can I learn of the history of the firearm and its manufacturer?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I wrote a answer for the manufacturer part. But if you want a history of your specific firearm (which is difficult enough), then imho it is not really possible to answer without knowing more details on what you actually possess (as opposed to some *partial picture of some other gun* that merely *looks "like" yours*). I'll upvote if you could either clarify this part or dispense with it.

Comment: The question of "possible value" is certainly out of topic here. This is not a site of antique dealers.

Comment: @Alex I am aware of this fact. However, there does not seem to be a better site on the stackexchange network.

Comment: The fact there are no stack exchange sites better suited, or in fact suited at all, for a question, does not make this one the go to place to post any random off-topic question.